# Copper Zones in intermediate planes

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I am developing a 4 layer PCB using KiCAD. It got 4 layers; Top, bottom, L1, L2. Setting copper zones for the top and bottom layers is common practice. I'm wondering, should I add zones to the intermediate layers as well (L1 and L2).

Also is it bad to create a zone which is not attached to any net? Just copper islands? Because KiCAD gives a warning saying it will create copper islands.

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: whether you should create copper areas or not depends on the signals you are handling. Generally copper areas in the intermediate layers can help shielding top from bottom, to create short return paths or to create controlled impedances for high frequency signals. Often it makes sense to have eg L1 as a GND plane and L2 as a power plane (or larger areas of these planes). So maybe you should tell us what you are doing on your PCB?

Comment: and those island planes could be unwanted for some high frequency applications. I think KiCAD mainly warns you about these because it is creating shapes in copper you did not specify.